# How to apply write_fst() function to each dataframe in list?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, fst

I want to save each dataframe from list with its according names as .fst file. My list with dataframes is called tables. I tried to do this, but it didn't work:

```
lapply(write_fst(), tables)
```

How to do that? How to perform write_fst function to each dataframe in list?

Comment: `lapply(tables, write_fst)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah but how to specify dataframes names to make them same as in list with .fst extension? also isn't it applying a function to list, not values in it separately?

Comment: Which package is `write_fst` function from? Do you have some example data?

Comment: @RonakShah its from library fst http://www.fstpackage.org/reference/write_fst.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `Map` -

```
Map(write_fst, tables, names(tables))
```

If the names of the list do not have extension (`.fst`) you can use `paste0` to add it.

```
Map(write_fst, tables, paste0(names(tables), '.fst'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through a list of data.frames:

```r
require(fst)

l = list(
  iris = iris,
  mtcars = mtcars,
  airquality = airquality
)

for (i in seq_along(l)) {
  write_fst(l[[i]], path = paste0(names(l)[i], '.fst'))
}
```